# Can transmission automatically move a download after it's done seeding, again?

Tags: transmission, bittorrent

I have setup transmission so that it initially downloads to a hidden file. After the download is done it gets moved to my Downloads folder, for immediate using. However i want transmission to move the download once more when it is done seeding, and, remove the entry from transmission. How do i do this?

Comment: how is one done seeding?!

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen by setting a seeding share ratio or seeding idle time limit under edit --> preferences. This can be manually overruled per torrent for those that need extra love. If thats not what you're asking then my answer is: teeny tiny hard drive.

Comment: well, I dont know, but why wouldnt you move it after completion and seed from there!?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen from the new destination it gets either (partially) deleted or moved to an external medium, without having to check in transmission whether its still active or not.

Comment: ahhhhh, ok. I dont know, maybe edit transmission(if the source is available) and add it in urself(if you are capable of that)?!